# Blank Screen after GUI Install

Tags: 12.04, installation, server, ati, gui

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04.2 x64 without a problem at all and I wanted to install the GUI (Ubuntu-Desktop).

I followed the below Steps:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Ubuntu went through the installation and then the screen on my Acer v193L went black and there is currently no output to the screen. The PC is doing something as the HDD Light flickering none stop.

The PC which I have installed Ubuntu on is a [HP 8000 Elite](http://h10010.www1.hp.com/wwpc/me/en/sm/WF06a/12454-12454-64287-3328898-3328898-4065889.html?dnr=1&jumpid=in_r2515_me/en/smb/psg/psc404redir-ot-xx-xx-/chev/) and has an [ATI Graphics Card](http://www.amd.com/uk/products/desktop/graphics/ati-radeon-hd-5000/ati-radeon-hd-5670-overview/Pages/ati-radeon-hd-5670-overview.aspx) installed.

If someone could point me in the right direction that would be great.

Thanks!!

Comment: Can you get to a tty terminal with CTRL+ALT+F3?

Answer (score -1):

Have you solved it yet? There seems to be numerous simliar questions on askUbuntu. 
The problems usually happen due to drivers ( I had the same issue with my nvidia)

For example:

- Here:http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1772710
- And here: [Blank screen after ATI video card installation on Ubuntu 11.10 amd64](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91352/blank-screen-after-ati-video-card-installation-on-ubuntu-11-10-amd64)